# Atom popup, really annoying

Tags: popup, hover, atom-editor

I have no idea what plugin is doing this, but it's incredibly annoying everytime I move mouse mouse to constantly get a popup.  When I am coping and pasting code it pops up, and I have to click somewhere else, and it blocks so much of screen.  Anyone know what plugin might be doing this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was happening because of the `atom-ide-datatip` package. I went into the settings for that package and unchecked *"Show datatip automatically on **mouse** hover"*, and checked *"Show datatip automatically on **cursor** stay"* as that got in the way for me less.

In my opinion, it would be nice if you could turn off those datatips for certain data types, like `int` and `str`. I mostly use this package for the function parameter popups.

Comment: Thank you! That was definitely a huge improvement!